# Using default values in Lombok @Builder overridden build() method

Tags: java, lombok, builder

Is it ever possible to access the default values of Lombok Builders?
I have some logic in my `Builder` that relies on that value being set, sort of like this:

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true, builderClassName = "Builder")
@Data
public class MyLombokClass
{
    @lombok.Builder.Default private final String name = "Default McDefaultson";
    private final String greeting;

    public static class Builder
    {
        public MyLombokClass build()
        {
            return new MyLombokClass(
                name$value,
                greeting + name$value);
        }
    }
}
```

So when it's overridden like this, we actually lose the default value of `name` when it hasn't been set:

```
void greet(String greeting)
{
    MyLombokClass lombokked = MyLombokClass.builder()
        .greeting(greeting)
        .build();

    System.out.println(lombokked.getGreeting());
    System.out.println(lombokked.getName());
}

>>> greet("Hello ")
Hello null
null
```

Now I have a very large object with lots of fields on, so I'd ideally like to move to using Lombok to reduce boilerplate code. However, the `build()` method requires logic to transform fields based on other values set in the class.

Ideally, what I'd like to be able to do is have the default value of `name` available before the object is built. That way, if the value is never set, we can still build correctly with an overridden `build()` method.

I can do this with a non-lombok class/builder, like so:

```
public static class Builder
{
    private String name = "Default McDefaultson";
    private String greeting;

    public Builder setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setGreeting(String greeting)
    {
        this.greeting = greeting;
        return this;
    }

    public MyClass build()
    {
        return new MyClass(
            name,
            greeting + name);
    }
}

>>> greet("Goodbye ")
Goodbye Default McDefaultson
Default McDefaultson
```

Whilst this is possible to solve with either a null check on a non-`@Default` field, or using the `name$set` flag, or by building the object then copying over the fields, it starts to become lots of hassle with lots of these fields, or a complicated `build()` logic.
This is an issue for me, cause I have a very large object which needs some fields to be either set explicitly or rely on default values **in the build() method** to control the setting of other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redefining the `Builder` class, redefine the two-argument constructor of `MyLombokClass`:

```
public MyLombokClass(String name, String greeting) {
    this.name = name;
    this.greeting = greeting + name;
}
```

IntelliJ reports an error about reassigning the `final` field `name`, but after annotation processing, `name` will not be final, so this will work if you actually compile the code.

Looking at the generated code from [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder), an alternative way is to check if a field is set by checking `fieldName$set`, and get the default value using the `$default$fieldName` method, declared as static in the outer class of `Builder`.

So this would work:

```
public static class Builder
{
    public MyLombokClass build()
    {
        return new MyLombokClass(
                name$set ? name$value : MyLombokClass.$default$name(),
                greeting + (name$set ? name$value : MyLombokClass.$default$name()));
    }
}
```

Note that again IntelliJ highlights the `$default$name` calls in red, seemingly cannot find them. But if you compile, it actually does work.

Similar to `xxx$value`, I'm not sure if these generated names are stable, and whether they will change in the future.